# Serializable class, what should be the field with spring

Tags: findbugs

If I have a Serializable class,

```
public class Solar implements Serializable {
@Autowired
private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
```

}

This message is shown when I Built the findBugs with this message :

> This Serializable class defines a non-primitive instance field which
>   is neither transient, Serializable, or java.lang.Object, and does not
>   appear to implement the Externalizable interface or the readObject()
>   and writeObject() methods.  Objects of this class will not be
>   deserialized correctly if a non-Serializable object is stored in this
>   field.

what should the fields be to don't look like bug?

Comment: IMO it does not have anything to do with Spring. Looks like it is only about (de-)serialization of a class which is serializable but defines a fields that isn't.

Comment: So It should be the fields serialization  too?

Comment: CategoryDAO should be Serializable too

Comment: I tried  [private  CategoryDAO  Serializable categoryDAO;]
it didn't work;

Comment: ``Serializable`` is defined on class level - like you did with ``Solar`` (not on field level).

Comment: yea that's right, I always misunderstand the Serializable levels very well.what should I added for the fields in this case?

Comment: If we are talking about a real DAO here, it should be rather marked ``transient`` - it does not make sense to serialize a DAO to me.

Comment: I got it know, Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

This does not have anything to do with Spring. Looks like it is only about (de-)serialization of a class which is serializable but defines a fields that isn't.

`Serializable` is defined on class level - like you did with `Solar` (not on field level).

However, if we are talking about a real DAO here, it should be rather marked transient - it does not make sense to serialize a DAO to me.

Comment: yes, I've noticed that IT should adds transient  for the DAO and BA class, But if I need the Serializable  for DTO or other object I have to Serializable  the class. Thank you I really learn one importent thing in this question! Thank you stackoverflow!

Comment: what just brought to me is that `serializable` or transient check should not happen to entity's field. Because it could be serialized in a converter.